# Selenium Python - Testing email functionality of my app using localhost SMTP

Tags: python, selenium

Checking if the emails are being sent from my application. I have created a localhost:25 SMTP in my application. Now i want to check if the emails are being sent to my localhost:25 SMTP. How can i achieve this by using Selenium Python?

note - i have a front end

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is used for automating browsers.  Since you are checking for emails, you could just use the Python [email library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html#module-email).  If you have a web frontend, then you could use Selenium to automate the front-end to make sure that the email was sent.